# Is it possible to call a function in Rust by naming its arguments?

Tags: rust

I don't know whether this is considered to be a good programming practice, but personally, I find that calling a function by naming its arguments makes the code more readable. I don't know whether this is possible in Rust programming language. I didn't find any named call expression in the grammar:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html

So for example the following doesn't compile:

```
fn add(n1 : i32, n2 : i32) -> i32 {
    n1 + n2
}


fn main() {
    let sum_value = add(n1 = 124, n2 = 200);
    println!("sum = {}", sum_value);
}
```

Therefore, my question is: Is naming arguments in function call possible in Rust and if the answer is yes, is it considered to be a good practice according to Rust best practices? (I'm a beginner)

Environment:

```
OS: Linux Ubuntu MATE 20.04.1 (64 bits)
rustc --version: rustc 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24)
```

Comment: You would usually have your IDE display the names for you, without actually having them exist in the code. [Like IntelliJ does here, for example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2690773/75097006-b5291a00-55b6-11ea-9bab-61364b06e8c9.png).

Comment: IDEs mitigate this issue only partially. As many arguments may be provided AND returned from function it's relatively easy to mix them up, and code review process is harder in such case -> as result systematic error may happen that will affect function of the system.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice if Rust allowed named parameters in function invocations. Code is much more readable that way, like in Python.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Therefore my question is: Is naming arguments in function call is possible in Rust

Rust does not support named parameters as part of the language.

> is it considered to be a good practice according to Rust best practices? (I'm a beginner)

Generally not (the rather strong typing usually helps mitigate this issue)

In cases where it really is useful two patterns crop up repeatedly:

- an *options struct*, the function would have a limited number of simple parameters and a named structure to pass more structured data, providing "naming"
- the builder pattern, which is an evolved and more literate version of the former (and more conducive to *optional* parameters)

See the article linked to https://old.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/fg6vrn/for_your_consideration_an_alternative_to_the/ for more information (I'm linking to the thread because there is useful discussion of the options, as well as links to helpful crates).

Comment: It would be nice to have a macro that mapped to the builder pattern. `name=>value` maps to `.name(value)`

Answer (score 22):

There is [an RFC open on this topic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/323).

Although not everyone in this RFC agrees, it seems that there is generally support for adding named and default parameters to Rust (including support from the core team). It seems the primary obstacle is not in the concept, but in the implementation.

As noted in the RFC, alternatives (such as the builder pattern) have the same issues as built-in named and default parameters, but also add large amounts of boilerplate.

Comment: If one day it is implemented, IMHO, it would improve drastically the readability and clarity of rust programs. Thanks for the link.

Comment: There're several important unresolved questions around the RFC. There're also several design alternatives. It isn't just about the implementation.

Answer (score 8):

No, there are no named/keyword parameters in Rust. They have been discussed [for a long time](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/323), but there are no concrete plans to add them.

If you have many parameters in a function, consider passing a struct, the builder pattern, etc.

By the way: the `add()` example does not show why named/keyword parameters could be useful, since the parameters are interchangeable.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that, while there are no concrete plans to add those features yet, it doesn't appear to have been ruled out; and there is quite a bit of discussion on the subject here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/323

Answer (score 3):

You can work around it with `#![feature(adt_const_params)]` if you're in nightly. It allows you to use `&'static str` contants as type parameters. It's clunky but it's still the best I could come up with so far:

```rust
#![feature(adt_const_params)]

pub struct Param<const NAME: &'static str, T>(pub T);

fn foo(
    Param(person_name): Param::<"person_name", String>,
    Param(age): Param::<"age", u8>,
){
    println!("{} is {} years old", person_name, age)
}

fn main() {
    foo(
        Param::<"person_name", _>("Bob".to_owned()),
        Param::<"age", _>(123)
    )
}
```

## The Good:

- The compiler will error out if you get the names of the params wrong, or if you try to use them in the incorrect order;
- No macros;
- No new types for every parameter in every function;
- Unlike the builder pattern, you can't set the same parameter multiple times.

## The Bad

- Nothing guarantees that the actual name of the function parameters and the `const &'static str` that you used are identical, which is disappointing but not very error prone;
- You can have multiple parameters with the same name;
- Syntax is pretty verbose on the call site;
- Getting the value out of the parameter needs either destructuring like in the example (thanks, [@Chayim Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman)
  ) or something like `person_name.0`;
- You can't change the parameter order, though that's pretty minor.

Comment: You can help with the `some_parameter.0` by destructuring the parameter: `Param(age): Param::<"age", u8>`. But then rustdoc won't show the param name :(

Comment: Being able to change the order is the #1 listed use cases for named params. Not "pretty minor." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter#Order_of_parameters

Comment: IMO, the main appeal of named parameters is correctness and legibility, in particular in cases where functions take arguments of the same type (e.g.: `offset` and `size`, `source` and `destination`, `x_offset` and `y_offset`, etc). Being able to change argument order is more of a convenience. Plus, I suspect there's no way to allow different argument order without producing runtime inefficiencies like extra temporary variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are no named parameters in the language, but they can be emulated with macros. See https://crates.io/crates/named for an experimental solution.